# Unexpected backwards compatibility or Why Isn't My App Crashing?

Tags: android

I'm developing an application with a `minSdkVersion` of 9, a `targetSdkVersion` of 17. I am performing some `Bitmap` pixel manipulation, so at one point I call the function `Bitmpap.setHasAlpha()` to enable the alpha channel for the `Bitmap` so I can set certain (and only certain!) pixels to be transparent.

The problem is that `Bitmap.setHasAlpha()` was only added in API 12--and this is where the mystery comes in. Lint is not complaining about my usage of this call (well... as a general rule. Every once in a while Eclipse will complain about it, and then when I restart it everything goes back to normal), when I run my app on a couple of different Gingerbread (2.3.3 and 2.3.5) devices everything runs properly.

So... as strange as this question sounds, why isn't my app crashing?

Comment: I want to upvote just because the question is so wonderfully backwards!

Comment: Haha... I was definitely aware of that as I was writing the title. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java?av=f       As you see mate the function existed before but not documented

Comment: surprising how fast you found an answer to this, haha

Comment: That explains it. I should've thought of taking a look at the source code right off the bat. Thanks, that's really helpful (and takes a load off my mind).

Answer (score -1):

**`minSdkVersion`** is a check designed to prevent download and installation of the app on older devices that do NOT have even framework corresponding to the `minSdk`.

**`targetSdkVersion`** is used to determine if any compatibility "workarounds" need to be enabled to ensure the behavior is as close to what is seen in `targetSdk`

By setting **`minSdkVersion=9`** you signal that the gingerbread devices be allowed to download and install your app. By setting 
**`targetSdkVersion=17`** you signal that any workarounds be invoked to allow the device to retain as much functionality as possible from the later sdk.

Also as mentioned in [Pulkits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871653/319204) the **[`setHasAlpha()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java/#706)** API seems to be present even in the 2.3.4 Android framework, albeit not officially documented at that time.